# Installing mod_perl 2 on Apache2 fails

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, mod-perl

I'm trying to install mod_perl 2.0.8 on a fresh installation of Apache 2.2.27 / RHEL 7.

Apache was built from source and installed to /usr/local/apache2. I then installed mod_perl with `MP_APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`. I edited my *httpd.conf* to read `LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so` and after a startup, the *error_log* shows "Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations", which would lead you to believe it works fine, but it doesn't. As soon as I try to access a site that lies in my */perl/* directory (I set that in my *httpd.conf*), that should be handled by mod_perl, I get an error 500. It was configured as stated in the [mod_perl docs](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html). My *error_log* then states "failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Can't locate loadable object for module Apache2::ServerUtil in @INC". I have checked my @INC directories several times and the files are there as far as I can tell. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by loading the module mentioned in the error_log in my httpd.conf with `PerlModule Missing::Module`. I then restarted the server and got another one of those error messages with another module. I repeated those steps for 15 modules and then got it working. I don't know what caused it in the first place but I'm glad it works now.